# Is it possible to open PDF files in Turbo C++ and if so, how?

Tags: c++

I am doing a project in C++ and I want to open PDF files. How can I do it in turbo c++? Do I have to switch to another IDE?

Edited:
I am doing an "E-book management" in c++. After managing the software i wanted to open pdf file through my program and do no access adobe reader or aome other. Sorry for incomplete question.

Comment: Do you want to open it with a PDF reader, or open it in you program?

Comment: This is a very vague question.  Do you want to view a PDF inside of the IDE or are you trying to open a PDF programmatically?

Comment: I want to view PDF in IDE itself.

Comment: It still isn't clear, what do you intend to do with the PDF? Are you looking for a way to access the contents of the PDF file by your program, which you write in C++ and compile in Turbo C++?

Comment: viewing the PDF within the IDE does not seem programming related

Comment: Why can't you open with Acorbat Reader ? Why do you want it to open it in IDE?

Comment: Questioned raised by Igor Oks is correct one. I am doing an "E-book management" in c++. After managing the software i wanted to open pdf file through my program and do no access adobe reader or aome other. Sorry for incomplete question.

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to open the PDF for viewing (like you probably do with your PDF viewer, e.g. Acrobat Reader), and not to open the file programmically, you cannot do it in Turbo C++ IDE.

Try opening the IDE in non-full-screen window, and you will be able to see the IDE and the PDF (in the Acrobat Reader) at the same time.

Comment: While the question is very vague indeed, why shouldn't it be possible? :)

Comment: Because when the asker mentioned the IDE, it became quite clear that he wants to open the PDF for viewing (like he does with the acrobat reader), and not to open the file programmically. Which isn't possible in Turbo C++.

Comment: @Igor - if that is the case then the question should be closed because it is not programming related.

Comment: i wanted to do it programmically.I mentioned IDE because turbo is older compiler and may not support different library support.

Answer (score 1):

You can add PDF support to your application with [TechSoft's PDF library](http://www.techsoft3d.com/products/fileformats_adobepdf.html?gclid=CLqB7vzmyJoCFQFHFQody18q3w). Which IDE you use shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

The [Poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/) library is a C++ library for rendering PDFs to any arbitrary format, whether to screen or image. It's very easy to extend, and I wrote a program for rendering PDFs to a custom image format in about 150 lines, in a little under 5 hours - and most of that work was in exporting the custom image format. A simple renderer came in under 50 lines and took me less than an hour to write.